# Excel VBA - replace last digit with a 1 if it is 0

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have a spreadsheet with a column of 2 and 3 digit numbers. If it's a 3 digit number that ends in a 0, that final 0 should be replaced with a 1. So 150 becomes 151 and 200 becomes 201.

This is what I was using, just to test the functionality, and it's very slow and usually crashes Excel because (I think) it's essentially doing a Find and Replace many times on every cell, even if it has already replaced the value. So I think I need to go a different route.

```
Sub FixNumbers()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Selection.Cells
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    c = Replace(c, "100", "101")
    c = Replace(c, "150", "151")
    c = Replace(c, "200", "201")
    c = Replace(c, "250", "251")
    c = Replace(c, "300", "301")
    c = Replace(c, "350", "351")
    c = Replace(c, "400", "401")
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If cells contain 2-3 digit numbers - do not use text operations on it. Format change should be outside of the loop.

```
Sub FixNumbers()
    Dim c As Range

    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
      If (c > 99) And (c Mod 10) = 0 Then c = c + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup, this is better.  I got caught by what the OP was doing and forgot simple math.

Comment: This answer works best for me, but there's one issue: if there's a cell with letters in it, I get a "Type mismatch" error. Is there something you can add to it to ignore cells with non-numeric characters?

Comment: @Robby add `If IsNumeric(c) Then` after `For Each` and `End if` before `Next`

Answer (score 2):

To do it in vba:

```
Sub FixNumbers()
Dim c As Range
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
For Each c In Selection.Cells

    If Len(c) = 3 And Right(c, 1) = "0" Then
        c.Value = CInt(Left(c, 2) & "1")
    End If

   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why set the `.NumberFormat` in the loop ??

Comment: Why set it at all? Surely it only sets the display choice?

Comment: I saw that just before your comment.  I focused on the one thing and missed that the OP had that in the code. @Gary'sStudent

Comment: @Chump as I commented in your answer, my guess is that the OP wants this to be dynamic based on the selection.  Maybe the OP gets reports from others and needs to format and change on a regular basis.  So the Op needs tha change of format as well as the ability to do a selection.

Comment: .NumberFormat does need to be set to "General." Sometimes I'm given numbers in this column with a different .NumberFormat, and this ensures that it is "General."

Comment: @Robby: I'm sure you're capable of removing that line. This is a good answer. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally do this by testing the value modulus 10, then adding 1:

```
Sub FixNumbers()
    Dim height As Long
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        height = CLng(c.Value)
        If height > 99 And height < 1000 And height Mod 10 = 0 Then c.Value = height + 1        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup, this is better. I got caught by what the OP was doing and forgot simple math.  The only thing missing is that the OP only wants the three digit numbers only to change.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Totally missed the 3 digit thing.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It didn't change any 3 digit numbers ending in a 0. But it did change some other 3 digit numbers. Examples: 146 became 145, 266 became 265, and 218 became 217.

Comment: @Comintern The edit is what I was using. Sorry. I should have specified.

Comment: @Robby - Forgot to hit submit on the edit I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in VBA. Mimicking something that worksheets can do wonderfully is pointless.

Instead create a new column in your workbook. Suppose column A contains your numbers.

Then in the new column use `=IF(MOD(A1,10),A1,A1+1)` copied downwards. (`MOD(A1,10)` is 0 if, and only if, the number ends in a zero).

Comment: I think that the OP wants to arbitrarily highlight some cells and have it done in place which would require vba.

Comment: You may well be correct: let's see what the questioner says.